# Getting java.lang.NullPointerException In Android webView

Tags: android

I am working on an application in which i scan a QR code and using that I am opening the pdf related to it. 
THIS IS MY CODE

```
if(uri.contains("abc"))
                {
    WebView webview= new WebView(getApplicationContext());

    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + uri);
```

but my application is crashing and i am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException`.
Please Help me. every help will be appreciated.
HERE IS MY ERROR LOG

```
03-15 18:26:03.150: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(4541): <ConfigWindowMatch:2081>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-15 18:26:03.160: D/memalloc(4541): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x519b7000 size:3010560 offset:2396160 fd:66
03-15 18:26:03.610: D/CameraConfigurationManager(4541): Default preview format: 17/yuv420sp
03-15 18:26:03.610: D/CameraConfigurationManager(4541): Screen resolution: Point(480, 320)
03-15 18:26:03.610: D/CameraConfigurationManager(4541): preview-size-values parameter: 640x480,640x368,512x288,384x288,352x288,320x240,176x144
03-15 18:26:03.610: D/CameraConfigurationManager(4541): Camera resolution: Point(512, 288)
03-15 18:26:03.620: D/CameraConfigurationManager(4541): Setting preview size: Point(512, 288)
03-15 18:26:03.780: D/CameraManager(4541): Calculated framing rect: Rect(60, 40 - 420, 280)
03-15 18:26:03.900: D/memalloc(4541): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x51f16000 size:6184960 offset:5570560 fd:72
03-15 18:26:04.100: D/memalloc(4541): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x525fc000 size:1843200 offset:1228800 fd:75
03-15 18:26:05.140: D/-heap(4541): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1322K, 22% free 6798K/8611K, paused 82ms
03-15 18:26:06.340: D/DecodeHandler(4541): Found barcode in 267 ms
03-15 18:26:06.360: D/-heap(4541): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1363K, 24% free 6817K/8867K, paused 19ms
03-15 18:26:06.380: D/CaptureActivityHandler(4541): Got decode succeeded message
03-15 18:26:06.530: D/MediaPlayer(4541): start() mUri is null
03-15 18:26:08.510: W/dalvikvm(4541): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40af39f0)
03-15 18:26:08.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4541): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-15 18:26:08.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4541): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-15 18:26:08.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4541):     at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:333)
03-15 18:26:08.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4541):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2711)
03-15 18:26:08.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4541):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2757)
03-15 18:26:08.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4541):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:419)
03-15 18:26:08.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4541):     at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:52)
03-15 18:26:08.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4541):     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:1092)
03-15 18:26:08.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4541):     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:1075)
03-15 18:26:08.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4541):     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:1064)
03-15 18:26:08.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4541):     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:1054)
03-15 18:26:08.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4541):     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:1045)
03-15 18:26:08.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4541):     at com.google.zxing.client.android.result.URIResultHandler.handleButtonPress(URIResultHandler.java:146)
03-15 18:26:08.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4541):     at com.google.zxing.client.android.result.ResultButtonListener.onClick(ResultButtonListener.java:38)
03-15 18:26:08.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4541):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3528)
03-15 18:26:08.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4541):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14235)
03-15 18:26:08.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4541):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
03-15 18:26:08.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4541):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-15 18:26:08.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4541):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-15 18:26:08.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4541):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-15 18:26:08.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4541):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-15 18:26:08.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4541):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-15 18:26:08.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4541):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
03-15 18:26:08.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4541):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
03-15 18:26:08.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4541):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: which URL you need to open in webview ?

Comment: I am Getting url via scanning the QR code.it the string got by scanning contains say abc then it should display the pdf related to it. otherwise it should simply open the url related to the QR code.

Answer (score 0):

Your WebView is flowing in air. Attach it to view hierarchy before doing anything or create webview via xml layout.